# Result of initializer is unused

Tags: swift, swift2

Result of initializer is unused, I get this error in this code:

[image]

Changing it like this silences it:

```
_ = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: true)
```

However it makes the code more uglier, is there a way to silence this warning without using the "_ =" ?

Edit, heres another example:

```
class SomeView: UIView {
    init(sender: UIViewController) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10))
        sender.view.addSubview(self)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SomeView(sender: self) ///Result of initializer is unused
    }
}
```

In this example since I am adding the subview from within the view, I do not need to use the created SomeView object in anyway.

Comment: I believe this method is deprecated now. You should use `NSURLSession` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil)?.start()
```

Comment: hello, that is a good work around, however I edited the question to include another example